# Elliptic curves and localizations at various primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $p$ be a prime at which $E$ has good reduction. Let $D=D_{E,p}$ be the $p$-torsion in the cokernel of the map $E(\mathbb{Q})\otimes\mathbb{Z}_p\rightarrow E(\mathbb{Q}_p)$. I would like to know how to better compute/describe $D$ as $p$ runs through all primes at which $E$ has good reduction. The group $D$ naturally arises in the study of certain p-adic BSD formulas (see the main theorem of Wuthrich's paper "Iwasawa theory for the fine Selmer group").

I am specifically interested in the case when $E$ has rank $1$. Let's assume for simplicity that $E(\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{Z}$. The group $E(\mathbb{Q}_p)\simeq \mathbb{Z}_p\oplus T$ where $T$ is the torsion subgroup of $E(\mathbb{Q}_p)$. The first factor comes from the formal group. I would like to understand how to check if the map $\mathbb{Z}_p\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$ obtained on composing $E(\mathbb{Q})\otimes\mathbb{Z}_p\rightarrow E(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ with the map to the first factor is an isomorphism. More specifically, I'd like to know if there are some arithmetic/Galois theoretic criteria for this to happen. For instance, is set of primes $p$ at which $D_{E,p}\neq 0$ finite?

(In the rank 0 case, the question is related to what are called local torsion primes, and there are heuristics to suggest that the set of local torsion primes are finite).

Comment: Suppose that $P$ is a generator of the free part of a rank 1 elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $M$ be the order of the reduced point in $\tilde E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ at a prime $p$ of good reduction. Then $D$ is trivial if and only if $MP\in\hat E(p\mathbb{Z}_p)$ does not belong to $\hat E(p^2\mathbb{Z}_p)$. There is a $\tfrac{1}{p}$ chance that this happens, so I'd guess that it might occur for infinitely many $p$. But I am not certain.

Comment: Instead for curves of rank$r >1$, I would conjecture that it is a finite number of $p$ as then the naive chance is $\tfrac{1}{p^r}$.

Comment: The fact that the set of primes at which $D_{E,p}\neq 0$ has density $0$ follows from conjecture 7.1 of Wieferich Past and Future by Nick Katz http://web.math.princeton.edu/~nmk/wieferich42.pdf and I think this is an open problem.